# Managing Compatibility with Older GNU Radio and VOLK Versions After Recent Major Updates

Tags: c++, compatibility, gnuradio, usrp

I am tasked with updating a project initially developed in 2017, which utilizes GNU Radio and USRP streamers. Our project was stable until recent updates to GNU Radio in November last year. These updates included a new version of the VOLK system (C++ libraries for vector and matrix computation) and significant changes in receiver streamers for USRP, notably in their class structures.

The updates for Python compatibility in GNU Radio are not a concern for our project. However, the changes in VOLK and USRP receiver streamers directly impact us. Our current challenge is determining whether we can continue using the older version of GNU Radio that our project was originally built on, without running into compatibility or functionality issues, especially considering the changes in USRP receiver streamers.

I'm seeking advice on the potential compatibility issues we might face using an older GNU Radio version alongside the latest USRP streamer updates. Additionally, any insights or experiences in transitioning older GNU Radio projects to work with these recent updates would be extremely helpful.

So far, we've conducted a preliminary assessment of the updated GNU Radio and VOLK versions against our project's requirements. We expected that the older GNU Radio version we've been using would be somewhat compatible with the recent updates, at least to a degree where minor tweaks would suffice. Specifically, we were hoping that the changes in VOLK and USRP receiver streamers would not drastically affect our project's architecture or its functionality.

However, upon initial testing, we encountered several compatibility issues. The project, which was stable with the previous GNU Radio version, now shows errors related to the receiver streamers. It appears that the changes in class structures and possibly other under-the-hood modifications in USRP are not aligning well with our current setup. We haven't yet delved deep into the new VOLK version's implications, but we anticipate potential challenges there as well.

We were expecting a smoother transition or at least clear pathways for adaptation, but the reality seems to be more complex. Therefore, we are looking for guidance on specific aspects to consider during the transition and any strategies that others have employed to successfully navigate similar updates.